# putting value in foreign key from primary key

Tags: cakephp

i have to select the name from the drop down list in cakephp.So the names id(primary serial key should store in the foreign key(moduleid),i m not getting the syntax proper.

in .ctp file

```
echo $this->Form->input('Modulepart', array('label'=>'Module','type' => 'select', 'options' => $modules));
```

in controller file

```
$fields = array('id','moduleName');

    $modules = $this->Module->find('list', array('fields'=>$fields,'conditions'=>array('isactive'=>'1')));

    $this->set(compact('modules'));
```

how do i set the field moduleid from the name automatically??

Comment: do you want to save module_id in your DB ?

Comment: what is the relation between both tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think may be your requirement may be saving of `moduleid` in DB, please try like this.

```
echo $this->Form->input('moduleid', array(
    'label'=>'Module',
    'type' => 'select', 
    'options' => $modules
));
```

May be This will help you.